# Researcher application in Norway

Tags: application, europe, application-cover-letter

I have recently obtained a PhD in engineering from a US university and am applying for a researcher position at a university in Norway. They are requesting an academic letter that includes "a description of scientific interests and motivation for applying".

I am treating this application letter as a cover letter. Can anyone with experience comment on the differences between applying to US positions vs Norwegian positions?
For example, how long should this letter should be? What are some key items that I should include in this letter? They mention that this position could lead to a tenure track position. Should I discuss my goal to become a faculty member? So far I am talking about my research interests, future research directions, experience publishing, and experience writing grant proposals.